# Rounding error for residuals in GARCH mean model

Tags: r, rounding

I have a GARCH model using `rugarch` package in `R` and I want to look into the residuals from the mean equation (`garch_model@fit$residuals`). These residuals have to have mean zero but because of the rounding error, it is giving me a tiny number of order `10^(-20)`. This messes up my further calculations. I tried using `round` with 5 decimals but that still doesn't solve the issue. Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: `round(10e-20, digits=5)` returns zero. So what is the issue that needs resolving?

Comment: I want to do ```mean(round(residuals))```, not ```round(mean(residuals))```. The reason is that I'm going to modify the residuals and ultimately take the mean, so checking the mean to be zero is more of a sanity check and not the end goal. @Edward